# Anime about spherical crystals that bestow power to their owners

Tags: story-identification, anime

I don't really remember many details, but I do remember these few things:

- There are a few spherical gem crystals which give power to their owners and their owners' weapons. There may be between 5-7 of those gems.
- There's a guy who has his stone in a cube-like thing
- Another guy, who I think is the main protagonist, keeps his stone in his sword/blade. His name is Kane or something.
- There's a villain trying to collect these stones
- One character keeps her stone in her knife

Does anyone know what anime this is?

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Is there anything else you can remember about this show? When you watched it, what language it was in, any other plot details you can remember?

Comment: May be english ... or some dubbed version can't remember. The main protogonist's gem is red and at first he keeps it in a pouch...then somehow got it in his sword ..i think when he uses it his eyes gets red